# Trying to hide elements in a woocommerce cart table

Tags: jquery, css, woocommerce, hide

[HTML example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV3tZ.jpg)

Hi,

I'm trying to select and hide elements in the table with the below css code but I can't get it to work.

```
.variation-PRICEgstinc {
display:none;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: There might be another style overwriting yours. can you post an image of the css on the right? That way we can see what's overwriting it.

Comment: With jQuery:

$('variation-PRICEgstinc').hide();

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Sorry looked through my wordpress/woocommerce files and can't find the CSS. The jQuery solution looks good. Not really sure where to paste it though and the proper syntax. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I managed to kind of figure it out. How do I hide the child elements of that class too? There would be around 100 different child elements so I would hope to be able to hide any child element of the class. Thanks